# Retrieving user data securely when user authenticates

Tags: node.js, security, vue.js, authentication, firebase-authentication

After spending some time reading about authentication and noticing it is pretty hard to do it well, I have decided to use firebase-authentication to authenticate my users in my vue app.

I'm listing the technologies and flow I use in this app to show each part interaction and clear things up:

1. I use Vue for my client javascript client
2. The client log-in users using firebase-authentication.
3. When user log-in, a call to a node.js rest api is done and a json is retrieved with its user data.
4. When the data is retrieved by the client, the app shows some parts     and hides other depending on user privileges

So, in my Vue application I show a custom login form and use it to authenticate users through firebase. After the user log-in, I retrieve some data from my own server (just a json with different user config values) that defines how the user can interact with the app (For example, what he can or can't do in my app).

How can I retrieve this information and use it in my client app in a secure way?. I mean, as an example, say I have a piece of information in that JSON that defines if the user is a regular or admin user. How can I avoid users to modify the response from the server and elevate privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything you can do to prevent client side DOM manipulation. If it's accessible via JavaScript, it's accessible to the user. It's up to you to implement your application in such a way that sensitive information and/or functionality is not dependent on client side security (if such a thing truly exists).

What you can do is prevent unauthorized access on the server. This is the purpose of defining scopes, ACLs, etc. If a savvy user does modify the response data and, say, change their role from `user` to `admin`, your response should not contain anything meant for admin users only. Rather, that information should only be accessible *after* making a successful API call where your server code has authenticated/authorized the request.

**Never** trust the client when it comes to security. That must be done on the server.

Comment: Do you think to SSR (Server side rendering) could improve security? This way the client is just a dumb terminal

Comment: The same principles apply for SSR. In the end whether an application is rendered in the browser or via server, users will have access to the DOM. The nice thing about SSR and security is you are able to handle part of the process without exposure to the world.